# Unable to push the URL with ID in react.js, React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency inside the array

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm unable to push the id with history.push
But if I don't add id then it works fine.
I'm using react-router-dom v5

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
  if (!userInfo) {
    history.push("/login"); // This portion works
  } else if (successCreate) {
    history.push(`/order/${order.id}`); // This does not work as expected
  }
}, [userInfo, history]);
```

// Here if I don't use order.id then it works, However I can console the order.id and it displays the id properly.
Is there any alternative to do the same thing in react. ? Or how to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, React Hook `useEffect` has a missing dependency inside the array.
You are not adding the `successCreate` in the dependency array, include it then it will work as you are expecting.

Modify your code to :

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
  if (!userInfo) {
    history.push("/login"); // This portion works
  } else if (successCreate) {
    history.push(`/order/${order.id}`); // Now this will work as expected
  }
}, [userInfo, history, successCreate]); // Modifed Line
```

Comment: Thanks faisal, that's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `order.id` has a value? It could be undefined maybe.
Literal string seems to be ok

Comment: Yes i have the id as Integer